# SSRS - Auto Redirect from a Report to Another Report

Tags: redirect, reporting-services, report

I have two reports: a 'List Clients' report  that lists the clients, and another 'Update Client' report that executes a stored procedure to update a flag in the client table.

The 'List Clients' report has an action on each row of the table that goes to the 'Update Client' report passing the client id as a parameter.

But I would like the 'Update Client' report to run and automatically return to the 'List Customers' report, listing the updated clients again.

Currently, the user needs to click on a 'Back Button', which I created, which has an action to go to the 'List Customers' report again. And I want the 'Back' action for the other report to be automatic.

How do I make a report, after it runs, automatically redirect to another report?

Comment: As far as I am aware this is not possible, though would be very interested to hear a solution if you find one, as I have in the past had the same set up you described.